# Get file's "get info" attributes in mac using python

Tags: python, macos, fileinfo

I have mounted a drive.

In it's "Get Info", I have an attribute named `Image Disk`

The location: `/private/var/run/vmware/fuse/10323660103412696815/flat`

How can I get this attribute using python?

`os.stat` does not give me this.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `getxattr` function from the `xattr` module, which is a Python binding to the native function [`getxattr(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getxattr.2.html).  For example:

```
import xattr
print xattr.getattr('/Volumes/MyDrive', 'Image Disk')
```

See [this blog post](http://technosophos.com/2009/02/09/python-mac-using-xattr-functions-get-extended-attributes.html) for a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanx but it doesn't return or print anything

Comment: @AliBZ: Is it possible the attribute isn't actually called "Image Disk", but rather something like "com.vmware.ImageDisk"? Try using ls -l@ or the xattr command-line tool to see. If that's it, just use the code from this answer with the right attribute name, and it will work.

Comment: Right -- `xattr -l` or `ls -l@` from the command line, or `xattr.lisxtattr()` in Python, will give you a list of all of the extended attributes of the file.