# How to get list of files on Mac that have been tagged by Finder with a color?

Tags: python, macos, tags, finder

I'd like to tag some files on my Mac with Finder under a certain color tag, and then be able to get that list of files using a Python or bash script. Is it possible to get the list of tags associated with a file via the command line or a Python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

But you'll have to rely on [xattr](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html), [xattr-lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr) should do the trick.
Some examples have already been made on how to use the `xattr` command line tool, those can be found here:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/possible-to-tag-a-folder-via-terminal
- [Get file's "get info" attributes in mac using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005303/get-files-get-info-attributes-in-mac-using-python)
- [How can I add OS X "tags" to files programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720376/how-can-i-add-os-x-tags-to-files-programmatically)

I hope these help you out.
In worse case you could use a tool called [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag):

```
tag -l file # list
tag -a tag1 file # add
tag -s red,blue file # set
tag -r \* file # remove all tags
tag -f green # find all files with the green tag
tag -f \* # find all files with tags
tag -m red * # match (print files in * that have the red tag)
```

This in combination with say [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) could solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but this is something that has been bugging me too — and I eventually came up with a run-round for tech-shy people that requires no line-command coding, just ordinary Finder commands and SimpleText. Try the following:

1. open a Finder window containing the tagged files and Select All
2. right-click on the selected files to get Contextual Menu and choose "Copy [x number of] files". If it doesn't say "Copy [x number of] files" but just "Copy [filename] you've accidentally deselected the files; reselect all, and try right-clicking again.
3. open SimpleText. Make sure that it is set to use Plain Text and NOT Rich Text. (Menu Bar: Format>Make Plain Text/Rich Text). If it is set to Rich Text, this technique will not work: you will get a document containing the actual files rather than a list of their names!
4. paste. This should paste a list of the *filenames* of all selected files, one per line, in the order in which they appear in the Finder. Hurrah!

Hope this works for you. It changed my life.