# Python Module xattr has no attribute list

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, xattr

I wrote a script which sets extended attributes on some files, with the module `xattr`. I successfully tested it in Ubuntu in python3, but it won't work on my RasperryPi.

I had to change a dozens of little errors, mostly like `xattr not knowing its methods`.

For example the `xattr.set(...) has to be changed to xattr.setattr(...)`. But I failed at listing them. So I tried the just the basics and get the error:

```
import xattr
xattr.list('files.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'xattr' has no attribute 'list'
```

I had the idea that maybe python is using the wrong module (for python 2.7 instead of 3?). So I tried to uninstall the 2.7 module but got this:

```
...$ pip uninstall xattr
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

But I could successfully uninstall the python3 package. After that the "import xattr" still worked even in python3?

Comment: What do you get if you type `dir(xattr)` after importing? And `xattr.__file__`? It sounds like you might have a file names `xattr.py` in your current path and it's importing that instead.

Comment: For dir(xattr) i get a list (of methods?):  [... '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_fgetxattr', '_flistxattr', '_fremovexattr', '_fsetxattr', '_getxattr', '_lib', '_listxattr', '_removexattr', '_setxattr', 'compat', 'getxattr', 'integer_types', 'lib', 'listxattr', 'removexattr', 'setxattr', 'xattr'], wich seems like the old version of the module.  But how can I force python to use the new one, if I cant delete the old one (see error above)?

Comment: What do you get for `xattr.__file__`? That will tell you where it is importing it from.

Comment: '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xattr/__init__.py'

Answer (score 4):

Its 3am, listening to the glitch mob and since I went down this rabbit hole due to my curiosity...  I wanted to give you my example of code to use the python's built `xattr` module.

Create a file called `xattr_example.py` and put this code into it then run the file.

### File:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# =============================================================================
"""The Following Is An Example for xattr."""
# =============================================================================

import xattr

print("{}".format(xattr.__file__))
# '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xattr/__init__.py'


def showww_me_the_meta(file_name):
    """Using Python's XATTR to list Key Meta Names for File."""
    print("Showing Initial Names & Values.")
    attrz = xattr.listxattr(file_name)
    result = ("A. Info Showcased Init: {}".format(attrz))
    print("{}".format(result))
    return result


def update_the_meta(file_name):
    """Using Python's XATTR to Update Key Meta Names for File."""
    xattr.setxattr(file_name, 'custom.comment',
                   'I tawt I taw a puddy tat!.'.encode('utf-8'))
    xattr.setxattr(file_name, 'Music.Artist',
                   'I did! '
                   'I did taw a puddy tat!'.encode('utf-8'))
    get_the_meta_values(file_name)
    return


def get_the_meta_values(file_name):
    """Example."""
    print("B. Listing Meta for: {}".format(file_name))
    attrz = xattr.listxattr(file_name)
    print("")
    for i in reversed(attrz):
        abc = xattr.getxattr(file_name, i)
        result = ("{} : {}".format(i, abc))
        print("   {}".format(result))
    print("")
    return


def remove_the_meta(file_name):
    """Example."""
    xattr.removexattr(file_name, 'custom.comment')
    xattr.removexattr(file_name, 'Music.Artist')
    attrz = xattr.listxattr(file_name)
    result = ("C. Info Removed Meta: {}".format(attrz))
    print("{}".format(result))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    showww_me_the_meta('xattr_example.py')
    update_the_meta('xattr_example.py')
    remove_the_meta('xattr_example.py')
```

### Result of running the file is:

```sh
$ python3 xattr_example.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xattr/__init__.py
Showing Initial Names & Values.
A. Info Showcased Init: ()
B. Listing Meta for: xattr_example.py

   custom.comment : b'I tawt I taw a puddy tat!.'
   Music.Artist : b'I did! I did taw a puddy tat!'

C. Info Removed Meta: ()
```

### Lastly

As far as `"import xattr" still worked even in python3?`  Please note that python can be installed for both versions but have different paths.

```sh
python -V
# Python 2.7.16
which python
# /usr/local/bin/python
```

and

```sh
python3 -V
Python 3.7.4
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

You must use `python` or `python3` respectively when calling `python` if you have more than one version listed.   I am working on a Mac OSX so I have both, but this script is was written in `python3`.

References:

- [Manual Pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html)
- [Using the xattr functions to get extended attributes.](http://technosophos.com/2009/02/09/python-mac-using-xattr-functions-get-extended-attributes.html)  <-- Found [link from SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005506/1896134)
- [Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.XATTR_SIZE_MAX)
- Only [usage examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96528/os.getxattr) that I could find.

Hope that helps!  Have a great one!

Comment: I also, added this to my Github repo https://github.com/JayRizzo/Random_Scripts/blob/master/xattr_example.py